# Device not responding to UART commands

Tags: arduino, uart, usart

I am using an Arduino mega2560 and an EZO EC(Electrical Conductivity) and am trying to send a command using the Serial.print() function. I am using the Arduino IDE 1.6.7.

I have some code that seems to work fine which I found online. But I want to know why my code will not work. The EC sensor does not seem to get the data I am sending. No data seems to being sent.

I know it is not my connection as I have tested the setup with the code that works it runs fine and as expected.

Here is the code I found online that works:

```
String inputstring = "";                              
String sensorstring = "";                             
boolean input_string_complete = false;              
boolean sensor_string_complete = false;             

void setup() {                                        
  Serial.begin(9600);                                 
  Serial3.begin(9600);                                
  inputstring.reserve(10);                           
  sensorstring.reserve(30);                          

}


void serialEvent() {                                 
  inputstring = Serial.readStringUntil(13);          
  input_string_complete = true;                       
}


void serialEvent3() {                                
  sensorstring = Serial3.readStringUntil(13);        
  sensor_string_complete = true;                      
}


void loop() {                                        
  float wt = 28.9;
  String tempCal = "T,";
  tempCal += wt;
  if (input_string_complete == true) {                
    Serial3.print(inputstring);
    Serial3.print("\r");                             
    inputstring = "";                                 
    input_string_complete = false;                    
  }

  if (sensor_string_complete == true) {               
    if (isdigit(sensorstring[0]) == false) {          
      Serial.println(sensorstring);                  
    }
    else                                             
      print_EC_data();                                
    }
    sensorstring = "";                                
    sensor_string_complete = false;                   
  }
}


void print_EC_data(void) {                           

  char sensorstring_array[30];                        
  char *EC;                                          
  char *TDS;                                          
  char *SAL;                                         
  char *GRAV;                                         
  float f_ec;                                         

  sensorstring.toCharArray(sensorstring_array, 30); 
  EC = strtok(sensorstring_array, ",");              
  TDS = strtok(NULL, ",");                            
  SAL = strtok(NULL, ",");                            
  GRAV = strtok(NULL, ",");                         

  Serial.print("EC:");                                
  Serial.println(EC);                                 
  Serial.print("TDS:");                             
  Serial.println(TDS);                               
  Serial.print("SAL:");                            
  Serial.println(SAL);                                
  Serial.print("GRAV:");                             
  Serial.println(GRAV);                               
  Serial.println();                                  

//f_ec= atof(EC);                                     
}
```

Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial3.print(9600);
}
void loop() {
  Serial3.print("R/r");
  Serial.print("R/r");
  delay(2000);
}
```

The Serial3.print just doesn't get sent to the sensor. But the other code also sends a string using the Serial3.print() function an it works fine. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

I understand that I need to write a procedure to take in anything that comes in from the sensor. But nothing seems to be even sent to the sensor in the first place!

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using slash, not backslash.  Change this

```
Serial3.print("R/r");
```

to this:

```
Serial3.print("R\r");
```

And don't use the `String` class.  It'll mess you up.  :)  Just use char arrays, and fill them up as characters are available in loop.  When the <kbd>\r</kbd> finally arrives, process the array:

```
char inputString[16];
int  inputStringIndex = 0;

void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if (c == '\r') {
      inputString[ inputStringIndex ] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate string
      inputStringIndex = 0; // reset for next time

      Serial3.print( inputString );
      Serial3.print( '\r' );

    } else if (inputStringIndex < sizeof(inputString)-1) {
      inputString[ inputStringIndex++ ] = c;
    }
  }
```

Do something similar for the response line.  This will also avoid blocking inside a SerialEvent.  :P

Comment: Hi slash-dev,okay I will try this. But how I understand the sensor, is that the sensor should send a "*ER" back to the Arduino Serial sort it is connected to.If it has been sent the command but those not understand it. It will send "*OK" if it understands it. So it should at least be receiving the command I send. e.g. if I send "R" then it should at least receive the command. But from my testing I know it does not even receive it. Can you explain why this is so?

Comment: Question: Why are you making it Serial.available() and Serial.read()? Should it not be Serial3? As I want to write straight to the Serial.3  do not want to use Serial0 at all. Or is this necessary?

Comment: @JohnB., your program uses `serialEvent` to read `input_string` from `Serial` (as in serial 0).  I assume that's a command to the sensor.  I just worked from your sketch.  Cut and paste my section of code to read from Serial3 and process the response when the <kbd>\r</kbd> finally arrives.  Also notice mhopeng's answer below: that `Serial3.print` in `setup` should be `Serial3.begin`, LOL.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My code has worked well now for over 2 weeks. Cheers : >>

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `setup()` block: before you can send data over a serial connection you need to configure the connection with a [`begin()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin) statement:

```
Serial3.begin(9600)
```

But in the code in your question you have

```
Serial3.print(9600)
```

And make sure that you have the EZO connected to the correct pins for [Serial3](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial) (14,15).

Also you need to use the "\" for printing control characters.